# How to have a shared background on a UIScrollView handling multiple ViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to make 1 UIScrollView that has inside of it 1 background which can be used by multiple ViewControllers. When the user scrolls to the next ViewController, the background should scroll with it. This is my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let leftViewController: StartLeftViewController = StartLeftViewController(nibName: "StartLeftViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(leftViewController)
        self.theScrollView.addSubview(leftViewController.view)
        leftViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        let middleViewController: StartMiddleViewController = StartMiddleViewController(nibName: "StartMiddleViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(middleViewController)
        self.theScrollView.addSubview(middleViewController.view)
        middleViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        let rightViewController: StartRightViewController = StartRightViewController(nibName: "StartRightViewController", bundle: nil)
        self.addChildViewController(rightViewController)
        self.theScrollView.addSubview(rightViewController.view)
        rightViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

        var middleFrame : CGRect = middleViewController.view.frame
        middleFrame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
        middleViewController.view.frame = middleFrame

        var thirdFrame : CGRect = rightViewController.view.frame
        thirdFrame.origin.x = 2 * self.view.frame.width
        rightViewController.view.frame = thirdFrame

        self.theScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.height)

        theScrollView.contentOffset.x = view.frame.width

    }
```

I already tried setting a background in the middleViewController which has an width of 3x, but I got problems adding elements to left/right ViewController causing the elements hiding behind the background. Thank you.

Comment: have you evaluated using just `views` instead of `viewControllers`?
Then there'll be one `ViewController` containing the `scrollView` & adjust its contentSize as its already implemented

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard you can place three Container Views into your scroll view, one after each other horizontally, and connect each of them with Embed segue to your corresponding view controllers.